# The value increments but goes back to zero instantly

Tags: java, field, inner-classes

I have here a code snippet of my Tetris project.

```
private class Game implements Runnable  {
    private int numDropped = -1;
    public void setCount(int count){
        count++;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
    public void run() {
        int column = 4, style = Piece.SHAPES[(int) (Math.random() * 7)][(int) (Math.random() * 4)];
        while (onPlay) {
            if (piece != null) {
                if (piece.isAlive()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }

            checkFullLine();  
            if (isGameOver()) {
                playItem.setEnabled(true);
                pauseItem.setEnabled(true);
                resumeItem.setEnabled(false);
                rightPanel.setPlayButtonEnable(true);
                rightPanel.setPauseButtonLabel(true);

                displayGameOver();
                return;
            }
            piece = new Piece(style, -1, column, board);
            piece.start();
            style = Piece.SHAPES[(int) (Math.random() * 7)][(int) (Math.random() * 4)];
            rightPanel.setTipStyle(style);
            numDropped = numDropped+1;
            RightPanel.scoreTextField.setText(numDropped+"");
        }
    }
}
```

The class `Game` is an inner class, by the way. Whenever a new piece goes down, the value of `numDropped` increments (as displayed in a JTextField) but then after a short while goes back to zero. Did I misplace the

```
numDropped = numDropped+1;
RightPanel.scoreTextField.setText(numDropped+"");
```

? Or because of something else like being `static` and stuff. Please help me. I'm kinda new in Java. Thank you very much!

Comment: *"Or because of something else like being `static` and stuff."*  Even if it is not *caused* by that, the attribute/code should probably probably be altered to allow it to be an instance attribute.

Comment: You have not posted enough code for us to help you.  How is this being invoked?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Actually, nothing will make this particular code decrement/reset `numDropped` under any circumstances.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik if OP invokes `setCount(numberSmallerThanCurrent)` it will

Comment: @Woot4Moo What do you mean? That will only update the `count` variable, which is never read anywhere (well, except in the getter).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik public void setCount(int count){
        count++;
    }   It is the third line of the posting

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the setter INCREMENTS THE VALUE as one + the supplied input.  That is my point.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Look closer: the setter is in fact a no-op. It increments its argument only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted will definitely never update the `scoreTextField` to a value that is smaller than the value it used earlier.

The first thing I would suspect is that there is some other code that updates `scoreTextField` to a value that is not equal to `numDropped`.

### Update

In your additionally posted code I see this:

```
RightPanel.scoreTextField = new JTextField(numDropped+"");
```

This is wrong; delete it and uncomment the line above, that sets the text on the existing text field.

Moreover, you've got this code:

```
timer = new Timer(
                500, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        scoreTextField.setText("" + game.getScore());
                        int scoreForLevelUpdate = game.getScoreForLevelUpdate();
                        if (scoreForLevelUpdate >= Tetris.PER_LEVEL_SCORE && scoreForLevelUpdate > 0)
                            game.levelUpdate();
                    }
                }
        );

        timer.start();
```

Clearly this will overwrite your `scoreTextField` with the game score, whereas in the `Game`'s loop you are writing the number of dropped elements. Judging from the name of your variable `scoreTextField`, you should change the code in `Game` to update some other text field and not the one used to display score.

Yet another thing that is wrong in your design is this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Game());
thread.start();
```

You are starting another thread to control the gameplay. You must not update any Swing components outside the main GUI thread, the so-called Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). My suggestion is to redesign your code similar to what you have done above with your `timer` variable: don't start another thread; instead schedule another `Timer` with the interval of 100 milliseconds, and implement the associated `actionPerformed` based on your current code in `while (onPlay)` -- all you'll need to change is that you don't need the loop anymore. Of course, `Thread.sleep(100)` will also be redundant. When the game is over, just `cancel` your timer task.

Not directly related to the problem of this question, but this code

```
public void setCount(int count){
    count++;
}
```

is also wrong: it doesn't write to the instance variable `count`, but just increments the supplied argument, immediately discarding it (it's just a local variable).

Comment: The `setCount` function can change the score.

Comment: @Woot4Moo What makes you think that `count` keeps the score? As the code stands right now, `count` has no purpose at all.

Comment: Good day. I have posted the whole class' code. For now, I'll follow your suggestions. @Woot4Moo

Comment: Thanks sir but when I do that, the text field always displays zero..

Comment: If by "when I do that" you are referring to my comment about `RightPanel.scoreTextField = new JTextField(numDropped+"");`, I should  point out that your problem is elsewhere. The line I quote is in fact a no-op: it will create a new JTextField, but that field will not be added visually to your screen; comment out that line and you'll see no change in behaviour.

Comment: I really appreciate your help sir. So now I've tried using a different JTextField so it will not be associated with `scoreTextField` and I did the same thing (the `RightPanel.numDroppedTextField.setText(numDropped+"");`) but after incrementing, the value just goes back to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The only two places I can see how it gets set to zero are as follows:

```
public int getScore() {
        if (board != null) 
            return board.getScore();
        return 0;
    }
```

AND

```
  public int getScoreForLevelUpdate() {
        if (board != null) 
            return board.getScoreForLevelUpdate();
        return 0;
    }
```

At some point your `board` object is getting nulled out, perhaps in the reset function.  Strap a debugger onto the process and place a break point in these two functions.